# Does unicode allow for multilevel bracketable subscripts like math does?

Tags: math, unicode, communication, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

Consider the following math expressions (which are not equivalent):

(e^x)^y

e^(x^y)

Can I write these in Unicode (with unlimited number of bracketable subscripts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode does define some specific codepoints for [superscripts and subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

There are some codepoints specifically for `x`, `y`, `(` and `)` as superscripts.  For your two specific examples, the closest you can get is something like this:

U+0028 U+0065 U+02E3 U+0029 U+02B8

```
(eˣ)ʸ
```

U+0065 U+207D U+02E3 U+005E U+02B8 U+207E

```
e⁽ˣ^ʸ⁾
```

In this second case, you cannot have `y` as a superscript of `x` when `x` is already a superscript of `e`.  In other words, something like this is not possible in Unicode:

[image: not possible]

If you tried putting the `x` and `y` superscripts together, it would come out like this instead:

```
e⁽ˣʸ⁾
```

You can, however, replace `x` and `y` with actual number digits:

`⁰` U+2070
`¹` U+00B9
`²` U+00B2
`³` U+00B3
`⁴` U+2074
`⁵` U+2075
`⁶` U+2076
`⁷` U+2077
`⁸` U+2078
`⁹` U+2079

For example:

```
(e¹⁰)²
```

Comment: Possibly my Stack Overflow client on Android does not support the Unicode symbols you inputted). Nevertheless, all I see I your answers is rectangles instead of characters. What if we tried with UT8 instead?

Comment: @JackMaddington: StackOverflow uses UTF-8 for its HTML. But regardless, fonts are based on Unicode codepoints, not UTFs. I have taken a screenshot of this answer and [posted it online](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ6Xq.png) for you.

Comment: Thanks. I guess even with Unicode you cannot do more than a simple basic math. I guess it's suitable for calculator buttons and that's it (as far as my purposes go).

Comment: Isn't there at least a set of codes that will allow you to subscript a word (like "hello")? What about UTF-8?

Comment: Subscripts/superscripts are specific codepoints, they don't work like combining characters that modify other codepoints. There is no codepoint that says "the preceding/following codepoint(s) is subscripted/superscripted." If you look at links I gave you, or even read the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/), you will see that there are a handful of letter-based subscript/superscript codepoints available, but certainly not all letters are represented.

Comment: And what about UTF-8 do you want to know exactly? UTFs are just encoding schemes of Unicode codepoints for storage/transmission purposes. They don't change how the codepoints themselves work. If you need to know more than that, please ask a new question about it.

Comment: Too bad Unicode/UTF-8 can't do everything the LaTeX typesetting system can do for mathematics and other systens (at least excluding diagrams).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98393/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-jack-maddington).

Comment: one more question: Can it be possible to make a negate variable in Unicode. f.e. an x with an overstrike ?

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair I don't understand what you are asking for, but please post it as a new question.

Comment: Unfortunately I am block to post new questions. What a pitty. I find it really bad. But in the meantime I found, that is not possible to overstrike one character with another.